# How to make sure docker service will start after containerd upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, service, unattended-upgrades

this morning I woke up to a 'service down' email I have received from watchdog.
After connecting to the server I have found the `docker` service down.
After little investigation, I have found that this morning Ubuntu made an unattended upgrade of the `containerd` service and after the upgrade, `docker` service was not started automatically.

How can I make sure that after the upgrade this will not happen again?

Comment: This is a bug in the containerd package and [has already been reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1870876?comments=all).

Answer (score 2):

I set Docker and its related packages to hold so they are only upgraded on planned upgrades.

```
sudo apt-mark hold docker containerd
```

When I want to upgrade Docker I run `apt-mark unhold`, upgrade the packages, and hold them again. I have an Ansible playbook to automate this process. My playbook to install and configure Docker sets the packages to hold directly after the installation.

Comment: Thanks for this. This acutally answers the question. The `containerd` upgrade fiasko was just an example of something that can happen.

Comment: is your ansible playbook available somewhere, like ansible-galaxy, or whatever?

Comment: No, it isn't, sorry. But it's pretty easy, you only need the [`dpkg_selections`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dpkg_selections_module.html) module for hold.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue. I opted for using a systemd unit file to create a loose dependency between containerd and dockerd.

Here's how:

As root:

Make the override directory (permission 755)

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/containerd.service.d/
```

Create the override file in the above directory (permissions 644)

```
vi override.conf
```

Add the following to the file

```
[Unit]
Before=docker.service
Wants=docker.service
```

Restart systemd daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Check it works

Stop containerd

```
systemctl stop containerd
```

Check dockerd has stopped

```
systemctl status docker
```

Start containerd

```
systemctl start containerd
```

Check dockerd has started

```
systemctl status docker
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Some links to other documentation on the subject

https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/

[https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html](https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) on docker restart policies is helpful, start your containers with the `always` or `unless-stopped` options as appropriate for your use.

It also seems reasonable to stop Ubuntu from carrying out unattended upgrades.

Comment: That doesn't help in this case. I had the same problem this morning, after the upgrade of containerd the docker systemd unit was in the state `disabled`.

Comment: That's a bug in the upgrade - it should be reported.

Comment: [It already is](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/containerd/+bug/1870514)